# CasperJS Request to Squid Proxy Generating HTTP Response 400 on ajax POST

Tags: post, casperjs, squid, http-status-code-400

I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with the following errors I'm getting nearly all the time when sending a POST request via casperJS.

```
this.open('https://'+host+'/test.php?test=new1', {
    method: 'post',
    data:   {
        'host':hostID,    
        'func':'newjob',
        'apikey': key,
        'test':testing
    }
})
```

The error 400 with the reasoning below is very cryptic and there is no reference to the error from Squid documentation.

1515876312.758      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4272 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876312.775      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4270 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876312.811      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4272 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876312.814      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4270 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876312.852      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4272 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876312.967      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4235 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876314.258      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4296 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876314.329      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4296 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876314.368      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4296 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876314.672      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4351 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876314.738      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4351 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876314.773      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4281 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876314.777      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4351 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html
1515876314.829      0 10.2.1.101 NONE/400 4281 CONNECT error:double-CR - NONE/- text/html

The output the CasperJS emits is:

```
 [info] [phantom] Starting...
 [info] [phantom] Running suite: 1 step
 Using UA=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8; de-at) AppleWebKit/533.21.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.5 Safari/533.21.1
 [info] [phantom] Step anonymous 1/1: done in 52ms.
 [info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3: done in 67ms.
 [warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: https://10.2.1.199/test.php?test=new1
```

I looked at this SO Q/A: [he following HTTP request returns a 400 ERR_INVALID_REQ -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41461877/squid-400-on-post-request)

which seems to be similar, but if they're connected in the problem - does anyone have any idea how to get CasperJS/phantomJS to not add a space?

Comment: I am not familiar with squid proxy, however are you sure you are providing all the required headers in your request?

Answer (score 0):

The issue  was a combination of the following:

Casper/Phantom apparently has two carriage returns on the requests, Squid 3.1 does not like this.

in squid.conf set:

relaxed_header_parser on

This does not stop the issue in Squid 3.1.x on a centos 6.x, but if you upgrade to squid 3.4 it fixes the problem.

Comment: As a follow up - this was due to windows style crlf on the input file I was using to select UA strings.  Changing to unix syle LF only solved the problem completely.